# Error connect to mysql server in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-12.04

I am trying to connect to mysql server in ubuntu 12.04 from terminal
using and password empty("")

`mysql -u root -p`

it throwing error

`ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to mysql server through socket 'var/run/mysql/mysqld.sock'(2)`

Though i am able to access database successfully from phpmyadmin and there i see there is no password for root in user user table in mysql database.

I am using xampp package

Comment: Is the mysql server started? `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start`

Comment: @Dan mysql server is already running i can access it through phpmyadmin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the error is the socket file. Where did you install your xampp?

Can you try this,

mysql -u root -p --socket=/opt/xampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock

where opt is your installation directory. Change opt to your installation directory.

edit:
Or if you don't want using socket parameter on your mysql command, you can try

ln -s /opt/xampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock /var/run/mysql/mysqld.sock

Thanks.

Comment: what is your xampp installation directory? Try to browse the xampp installation directory and look for mysql.sock or mysqld.sock. or try this ps -ax|grep mysql. see if you can find the socket file of your mysql.

Comment: I found file at /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock but it's empty

Comment: ok. it supposed to be empty. weird because your mysql should work.but whats the result of ps -ax|grep mysql? we may find the answer in that.

Comment: Try this. mysql -u root -p --socket=/opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock

Comment: Thanks it works, but what is problem i don't understand

Comment: The mysql client you are using is connecting using the socket /var/run/mysql/mysqld.sock you can edit your /etc/mysql/my.cnf or /etc/my.cnf. Under the [client] edit the socket part where i think it is pointed at  /var/run/mysql/mysqld.sock. Change it to /opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock. Or try again the symbolic link ln -s /opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock /var/run/mysql/mysqld.sock. Delete the mysqld.sock that is currently there. Then you can issue the command mysql -u root -p without any problems. glad i can help.

Answer (score 0):

what i can guess about your problem:following

If your file my.cnf (usually in the /etc/mysql/ folder) is correctly configured with

```
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
```

you can check if mysql is running with the following command:

```
mysqladmin -u root -p status
```

try changing your permission to mysql folder. If you are working locally, you can try:

```
sudo chmod -R 755 /var/lib/mysql/
```

that solved it for me