# xampp, php, and mysqld.sock

Tags: php, apache, xampp

I'm trying to set up a laravel app.  The app is set up, but when I try to run a migration to create a table I get the following error:

```
[PDOException]                                                               
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '  
/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

Now I am running xampp on ubuntu.  I'm not sure why its searching in this directory.  When I run my phpinfo, it tells me that mysqld.sock is located at: /opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock.

I'm not sure if the php_cli module reads from a different ini file or something like that.  Has anybody had experience with this issue or have any ideas to point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is the socket file. Where did you install your xampp?

Can you try this,

mysql -u root -p --socket=/opt/xampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock

where opt is your installation directory. Change opt to your installation directory.

edit: Or if you don't want using socket parameter on your mysql command, you can try

ln -s /opt/xampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock /var/run/mysql/mysqld.sock

Thanks.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/20535780

Answer (score 0):

IN MacOS:

Step 1: Go to your Finder and edit the file as the following path below.
`/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/my.cnf`

Step 2: Open the file and find the [mysqld] section
add one line as following
`innodb_force_recovery = 1`
,and save.

Step 3: Run command in your Terminal
`sudo /Applications/XAMPP/bin/mysql.server start`
Wait until everything is OK.

Step 4: Edit the my.cnf again and remove the line you just added
`innodb_force_recovery = 1`
,and save.

Step 5: Stop for restart
`sudo /Applications/XAMPP/bin/mysql.server stop`
Wait until everything is OK.

Remind that if you didn’t passed this step your all tables will be read only.

Step 6: Open XAMPP Manager and click “Start” button to start MySQL Database again
The progressing status will show “Running”.

NOTE: This problem will be faced again, after you restart your Mac OS X. So, you have to repeat these steps again. Remember that this is the workaround solution.

[Source](https://www.areyoucodingenough.com/query-technics-database/solution-mysql-database-doesnt-start-xampp-mac-os-x/)